# Change the Reference Moving Point of an Object Using Click Event

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

The point I need help is that when I try to do **a click event**, a different point of a picture box object should be positioned, not **the top left corner**.

Is there a way to **change the reference moving point of an object**?

**Example:**

The point shown as "**Yellow Circle**" is the reference point where the "**pictureBoxRed**" object is located in any **mouse click event**.

The point shown as "**Black Star**" is a point indicating the position to be clicked for example.

If the sample point shown as "**Black Star**" is clicked with the left cursor, it must be moved from the "**Yellow Circle**" point of the "**pictureBoxRed**" object, not the upper left corner point of the "**pictureBoxRed**" object.

Thanks for your aid.

[**Here Example Gif Animation About This Problem**](https://media.giphy.com/media/2vjmJU3q59nUpb4lNh/giphy.gif)

```
    private void Exmp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        GeneralClick(e.Button, e.X, e.Y);
    }

    PictureBox picRed = new PictureBox();
    PictureBox picBlue = new PictureBox();

    private void GeneralClick(MouseButtons sender, int X, int Y)
    {
        if (sender == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            picRed.Location = new Point(X, Y);
            var arrayer = this.PointToScreen(picRed.Location);
            arrayer = picBlue.PointToClient(arrayer);
            picRed.Parent = picBlue;
        }
    }
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        picBlue.MouseClick+= new MouseEventHandler(Exmp);
    }
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I've edited my post.

Comment: Is there someone who can find any solution?